# Mail sending in laravel-not showing errors and not sending email

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

Here I am not storing the contact details in the database. I just want to send the contact form data to mail but I don't get any error and also not receiving mail. I am using my Gmail account for this and also enabled the less secure access in my google account setting. After submitting the form it comes on the same page.what should I do for this to be worked.

**.env file:-**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**Controller:-**

```
function sendmail(Request $request)
   {
$this->validate($request,[
'name' =>'required',
'email'=>'required|email',
'phone'=>'required',
'message'=>'required']);

\Mail::send('contact_email',
array(
'name' => $request->get('name'),
'email' => $request->get('email'),                 
'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
'bodyMessage' => $request->get('message'),
), function($message) use ($request)
{
$message->from($request->email);
$message->to('harsha1604gandhi@gmail.com');
});
return back()->with('success', 'Thank you for contact us!');
}
```

**View:-**

```
<form action="contact" method="POST" class="row">
{{csrf_field()}}
<!-- name -->
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control main" placeholder="Name" required>
</div>
<!-- email -->
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="email" class="form-control main" placeholder="Email" required>
</div>
<!-- phone -->
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control main" placeholder="Phone" required>
</div>
<!-- message -->
<div class="col-md-12">
<textarea name="message" rows="15" class="form-control main" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
</div>
<!-- submit button -->
<div class="col-md-12 text-right">
<button class="btn btn-style-one" type="submit">Send Message</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**emails.contact.blade.php**

```
<h2>Hello Admin,</h2>
You received an email from : {{ $name }}
Here are the details:
<b>Name:</b> {{ $name }}
<b>Email:</b> {{ $email }}
<b>Phone Number:</b> {{ $phone }}
<b>Message:</b> {{ $message }}
Thank You
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `name="email"` in the email input, change it to

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control main" placeholder="Email" required>
</div>
```

Your form validation is failing because it has `'email' =>'required|email'` but you are sending no email due to the missing name value.

Answer (score 0):

Mail::send needs to be passed an instance of a Mailable object.

[Sending Mail docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#sending-mail)

Edit: sorry, I see Laravel allows your approach too.

Also, remember if you're using the config cache you need to flush it after making changes to .env